# Como inserir ícones do próprio Wordpress no menu da área administrativa?

Tags: php, wordpress

Como setar ícones do próprio Wordpress, ícone que fica localizado na linha `10` desta função?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'pagina_gerencia');

function pagina_gerencia() {
    add_menu_page (
    'Gerência de dados',
    'Gerência',
        'manage_options',
        'danton_traduttions/danton_traduttions.php',
        '',
        'div', // <-- linha 10
        6
    );
}
```

Comment: oh, dear lord, porque os #'s de linha? Marca a linha 
com um comentário, senão o copy/paste fica comprometido.

Comment: só pra leitura ficar mais fácil !!!

Comment: E a linha 10? Por favor, confira [O que fazer quando o O.P muda sua pergunta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1682/201)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só usar uma das classes do [**`dashicons.css`**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css#L168), como `dashicons-chart-pie` ou `dashicons-welcome-learn-more`:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    # $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function = '', $icon_url = '', $position = null
    add_menu_page (
        'Gerência de dados',
        'Gerência',
        'manage_options',
        'gerencia_de_dados',
        function(){ echo '<h1>menu</h1>'; },
        'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
        6
    );
});
```

[image]

Também pode colocar uma URL, um *base64-encoded SVG* ou deixar vazio para fazer com CSS.

Comment: Se você desse um **like** para as perguntas ia ser muito legal, estimula a comunidade. Tem dias que eu saio dando **likes** nas suas perguntas e respostas assim como faço com vários outros da comunidade. Pensa nisso.

Comment: é minha prática comun, viajei... mas agora vou dar um tempo para não parecer que cedi à pressão :P

Comment: Não sei se essa questão merece a abertura de uma pergunta: a partir do momento que eu setei os arquivos que o menu puxa e que os dados trabalhados não tem nenhuma relação direta com funções do Wordpress em si, posso colocar o que bem entender nos meus arquivos `.php`? ... tipo fingir que aquilo alí está integrado com Wordpress só porque tá dentro da área administrativa?

Comment: Não é fingir, o que vc fizer `include/require` vai ter o WP disponível. Tem que organizar o código direitinho e tá tudo bem...

Comment: Sabia que tinha alguma coisa errada, estava muito fácil !!! Erro de `Cannot modify header information` headers. rsrsrs